# lowering voltage of high frequency signal

Tags: voltage-divider, high-frequency, ram

One of the parts I have is RAM (1.5V logic level).

The hardware communicating with it, is at a 1.8V logic level. The RAM signals are sent quickly - around 350-450Mhz.

So I am pretty sure I can't just blast the ports with 1.8V - or can I? The reference voltage of the RAM IO ports is set according to the datasheet (.6 * 1.5V).

Do I need a voltage divider to drop the voltage? And if I do, will standard chip resistors be alright at that frequency?

Comment: There's a lot more to this than you are yet worrying about.  What is the actual application  need that has you putting down memories on a custom board?  What is the exact part they are interfaced to, what is the exact part of the memories, and why do you want to use those particular memories rather than ones that are more compatible?

Comment: Its connected to an FPGA, whose IO can be referenced down to 1.8V. Most of the RAM parts I found had their VCC around 1.8V, but then their data line IO were referenced to .5 or .6 of it's VCC.

Comment: Again, the actual part numbers are???